# Flutter and Aws RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-rds

I am new to flutter I want to work with AWS Rds as a backend with my flutter I searched in google but I only found is Aws Amplify Concept, So can I do with Aws Rds as a MySQL database

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can connect AWS RDS with aurora SQL and use Lambda functions to internally interact with AWS RDS and return result to you flutter app.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.